# Telegram bot not working on Heroku with no logs

Tags: python, heroku, telegram

I used Heroku free account to deploy my 3 Telegram bot using Python Telegram Bot. In each there is a sqlite DB.
From 10 days (or more) no one works. The logs is empty. I tried to deploy them again but nothing, they still not working and in the logs there is only the new deploy.
Has anything changed in Heroku or in the API?

Comment: As far as I know, Heroku dynos can work 1000 hours per month for free, so may be your dyno time was exceeded?

Comment: Since late November, 2022 Heroku no longer offers free services.